# Group by with union mysql select query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, union

```
(SELECT COUNT(motorbike.`owner_id`) as count,owner.`name`,transport.`type` FROM transport,owner,motorbike WHERE transport.type='motobike'
AND owner.`owner_id`=motorbike.`owner_id`
AND transport.`type_id`=motorbike.`motorbike_id` GROUP BY motorbike.owner_id)
UNION ALL
(SELECT COUNT(car.`owner_id`) as count,owner.`name`,transport.`type` FROM transport,owner,car WHERE transport.type='car'
AND owner.`owner_id`=car.`owner_id`
AND transport.`type_id`=car.`car_id` GROUP BY car.`owner_id`)
```

The query above returns a result like this below,

```
count          name
1              Linda
2              Mary
1              Steve
1              Linda
```

This query is to count how many transport that owned by an owner. Linda have one car and one motorcycle,so the result should:

```
count          name
2              Linda
2              Mary
1              Steve
```

I have tried this query,but return error:

```
(SELECT COUNT(motorbike.`owner_id`),owner.`name`,transport.`type` FROM transport,owner,motorbike WHERE transport.type='motobike'
AND owner.`owner_id`=motorbike.`owner_id`
AND transport.`type_id`=motorbike.`motorbike_id`)
UNION ALL
(SELECT COUNT(car.`owner_id`),owner.`name`,transport.`type` FROM transport,owner,car WHERE transport.type='car'
AND owner.`owner_id`=car.`owner_id`
AND transport.`type_id`=car.`car_id`)  GROUP BY motorbike.owner_id
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

```
select sum(qty), name
from (
    select count(m.owner_id) as qty, o.name
    from transport t,owner o,motorbike m
    where t.type='motobike' and o.owner_id=m.owner_id
        and t.type_id=m.motorbike_id
    group by m.owner_id

    union all

    select count(c.owner_id) as qty, o.name,
    from transport t,owner o,car c
    where t.type='car' and o.owner_id=c.owner_id and t.type_id=c.car_id
    group by c.owner_id
) t
group by name
```

Comment: Such a simple way to do it, yet I never would have thought of that.  Awesome!

Comment: How do you add order and limit to?

Comment: @DavidAddoteye you add order and limit to the very end.  You can order on any of the outermost selected columns: `sum(qty)` or `name` in this example.

Answer (score 9):

This may be what your after:

```
SELECT Count(Owner_ID), Name
FROM (
    SELECT M.Owner_ID, O.Name, T.Type
    FROM Transport As T, Owner As O, Motorbike As M
    WHERE T.Type = 'Motorbike'
    AND O.Owner_ID = M.Owner_ID
    AND T.Type_ID = M.Motorbike_ID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT C.Owner_ID, O.Name, T.Type
    FROM Transport As T, Owner As O, Car As C
    WHERE T.Type = 'Car'
    AND O.Owner_ID = C.Owner_ID
    AND T.Type_ID = C.Car_ID
)
GROUP BY Owner_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this EDITED:

```
(SELECT COUNT(motorbike.owner_id),owner.name,transport.type FROM transport,owner,motorbike WHERE transport.type='motobike' AND owner.owner_id=motorbike.owner_id AND transport.type_id=motorbike.motorbike_id GROUP BY motorbike.owner_id)

UNION ALL

(SELECT COUNT(car.owner_id),owner.name,transport.type FROM transport,owner,car WHERE transport.type='car' AND owner.owner_id=car.owner_id AND transport.type_id=car.car_id GROUP BY car.owner_id)
```

Comment: What's the error that you are getting? If i have the error text, I can better debug the problem

Comment: Error Code : 1064
This is error i get. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY car.owner_id

Comment: Its run correctly. But the result still same. Linda appear twice as she have one car and one motorcycle. I want to make Linda appear once with count = 2