# SQL divide count grouped by the same value from different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table with two rows containing names and some other stuff, these two columns can contain the same name:

| Buyer | Seller | RegionID | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Lina | 1 |  |
| Lina | Kajsa | 2 |  |
| John | Conny | 5 |  |
| Kajsa | Conny | 3 |  |
| John | Erik | 2 |  |
| Kajsa | Conny | 1 |  |
| John | Conny | 2 |  |
| John | John | 1 |  |
| John | Conny | 1 |  |
| Kajsa | David | 1 |  |
| David | David | 1 |  |

Lets call this table **Store**,
I can do queries like this:

```
select Buyer, count(*) from Store where RegionID=1 group by Buyer
```

to get how many buys a person has made, and can make similar query for Seller by replacing Buyer with Seller.

These queries would give me something like this:

| Buyer | count(*) |
| --- | --- |
| John | 3 |
| Kajsa | 2 |
| David | 1 |

| Seller | count(*) |
| --- | --- |
| Lina | 1 |
| Conny | 2 |
| John | 2 |
| David | 2 |

**So what I want to do is to make a query that list each unique name in one column, and the buyer count divided by the seller count in a second column. But I can't figure out how to do that.**

**I basically want to be able display all of Johns buys divided by his sells.**

Comment: So are `John` from Seller, the same `John` from Buyer?

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572821/group-by-with-union-mysql-select-query)

Comment: @DavidMcEleney Yes!

Comment: @gimix I have looked at that post but I don't understand how it translates to my query, my knowledge of SQL is very limited, could you maybe give me an example?

Comment: @Rami the answer below is the solution. Also note the `HAVING Sum(sellercount) > 0` clause which prevents possible division by zero errors

Comment: @gimix Hmm ok, can't seem to get it to work. Getting an error that I posted as a comment to that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT clinetname,
       Sum(buyercount) / Sum(sellercount)
FROM   (SELECT buyer    AS ClinetName,
               Count(1) AS BuyerCount,
               0        AS SellerCount
        FROM   Store
        WHERE  regionid = 1
        GROUP  BY buyer
        UNION ALL
        SELECT seller   AS ClinetName,
               0        AS BuyerCount,
               Count(1) AS SellerCount
        FROM   Store
        WHERE  regionid = 1
        GROUP  BY seller) a
GROUP  BY clinetname
HAVING Sum(sellercount) > 0;
```

Comment: I can't get this to work, get the error:
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'sellercount' in 'field list'
Where does buyercount and sellercount come from in 

SELECT clinetname,
       Sum(buyercount) / Sum(sellercount)

Comment: I believe the `sellercount` line in the last `SELECT` column list is a typo and should be removed

Comment: I edited the answer, hope Courser is ok with that :)